# Java FTP LIST command

Tags: java, ftp

Hello I am in the process of making a FTP client for a uni project and before starting I am experimenting with the basic commands of the FTP protocol. So far I have been able to login successfully to a FTP server. Now, what I want to do is to list the root directory in order to get it's contents.

I have implemented this method to do what I describe but I can't seem to make it work. As far as I can tell it does go into passive mode, but when I issue the list command nothing happens. I cannot understand why this is happening. Can anyone help?

Here is the code in question:

```
public synchronized boolean list() throws IOException{
        sendLine("PASV");
        String response = readLine();
        if(!response.startsWith("227 "))
            throw new IOException("Could not request PASSIVE mode: " + response);

        String ip = null;
        int port = -1;
        int opening = response.indexOf('(');
        int closing = response.indexOf(')', opening + 1);

        if(closing > 0){
            String dataLink = response.substring(opening + 1, closing);
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(dataLink, ",");
            try{
                ip = tokenizer.nextToken() + "." + tokenizer.nextToken() + "." + tokenizer.nextToken() + "." + tokenizer.nextToken();
                port = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()) * 256 + Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw new IOException("Received bad data information: " + response);
            }        
        }


        sendLine("LIST");
        response = readLine();
        return (response.startsWith("200 "));
    }
```

Comment: Where do you open the data connection? Where is the `PORT` command?

Comment: I have other methods that deal with connecting to the FTP server. May I ask why should I use the PORT command? Can't I just list a directory while being in passive mode? (Sorry for the question but I am new to this an I still haven't gotten the feel of it).

Comment: You are right, sorry; in PASV mode you don't need the PORT command, but you do need to connect to the port the server sends you and you don't seem to be doing it here... You grap the IP and port but do not open the socket.

Comment: OK I see. So how should I enter passive mode? Should I just issue the list command and then open a new socket to handle this?

Comment: Perhaps you should find a few example FTP sessions online, and see if you can follow what's happening in them. Basically, listing a directory is asking for data (text containing the names of the files), so that data is returned through the data connection rather than the control connection.

Comment: On the result of the PASV command you obtain a 227 reply which contains information which you should use in order to establish the data connection; the next command (here, LIST) will pour data into that connection. Use that.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot! I have made it work. After what you suggested I handled the data from the FTP using a BufferedInputStream and I successfully listed the directory.

Comment: I suppose I can use the same basic logic for downloading files as well? Entering into passive mode using and then selecting the file I would like to download?

Comment: @Aris Yes. Listing directory in FTP is basically a "file" download too. So it's the same logic as for actual file downloading.